# непонятное открытие устройства

Tags: linux, c, dnsmasq

Изучаю код dnsmasq старую версию. Меня интересует вот этот кусок кода. Там есть комментарий, но по нему всё равно не пойму, потому что код как будто не логичный. Этот код пишется почти в начале программы.
Вот он

```
for (i = 0; i < max_fd; i++)
  if (i != STDOUT_FILENO && i != STDERR_FILENO && i != STDIN_FILENO)
    close(i);
  else
    open("/dev/null", O_RDWR);
```

Там где close понятно, закрываются все дескрипторы, но open не присваивается никуда. В комментах написано что-то о 0, 1, 2, ну stdout, stderr, stdin. Но как? Или это в ассемблерном коде в цикле i будет как eax, и open как раз в eax заносит файловый дескриптор?

Comment: Я так это вижу. 1. Закрыть все дескрипторы, кроме stdin, stdout, stderr. 2. Последние перенаправить в */dev/null*.

Comment: @0andriy, и как вы это видите? Как последние перенаправляются, если они никак не обозначаются при открытии?

Answer (score 1):

Присвоение опен к цему-то не имеет смысла так как этот дескриптор закроется на следующих итерациях. Код больше похож на то что в нем хотят убедиться что дескрипторы 0,1,2 будут открыты по номеру, даже если STDOUT_FILENO, STDERR_FILENO, STDIN_FILENO переопределенны на другие номера.

Похоже на воркэраунд какого-то бага на какойто архитектуре или для дальнейшей оптимизации.

Открой историю коммитов на этом месте и посмотри что там пишут.